# Jquery Ui Auto suggestions with Json array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery UI auto completion to give the project name suggestion in a list. I'm providing a project name list as a json array from the php file as follows.

```
function getProjectList($projectList) {
    foreach ($projectList as $project) {
        $jsonArray[] = array('name' => $project['projectName'], 'id' => $project['projectId']);
    }

    $jsonString = json_encode($jsonArray);
    return $jsonString;
 }
```

And I'm geting the whole project name list to a javascript variable.

```
var projectsForAutoComplete=<?php echo $timesheetForm->getProjectListAsJson(); ?>;
```

This project list have more than 10000 projects and I'm have 20 project name text boxes which should provide the auto suggestions. So when I try to do it as follows at the load time the page get 30 seconds to get load due to higher procession of the js.

```
$(".project").autocomplete(projectsForAutoComplete, {

    formatItem: function(item) {
    var temp = $("<div/>").html(item.name).text();
        return temp.replace("##", "");
    }
    ,
    matchContains:true
})
```

So I need to load the auto suggestions in the key press event as in the demo in the Jquery Documentation. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

But the example shows how to do it with a remote json source. Can I do the same with the local json array. Is it possible. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the json array on the page then you can simply include it as a source

```
source: projectsForAutoComplete
```

However, autocomplete expects it's source to be a 1D array and your array is 2D. You'll either need to make two arrays, provide the one with the strings as the source, and write a function to map the name to the id, or do something similar to the combobox example in the jQueryUI autocomplete documentation.